# "cannot be cast to" error with two images and seekbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have 3 items on screen: SeekBar, Background img, Rotatable img.
Task: to draw 2 images: gauge and a needle and later depending on seekbar progress to rotate the needle.
The problem occurs when i try to uploading to tablet

```
07-10 09:52:13.680: E/AndroidRuntime(30494): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aaa.samples.thermometer/com.aaa.samples.meter.MeterActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.aaa.samples.meter.MeterActivity cannot be cast to android.widget.SeekBar$OnSeekBarChangeListener
```

Tried a lot of different setups with relativelayout etc. no luck

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="150" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/spidometras" />
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/rodykle" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

Class if needed:

```
seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);



    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener((OnSeekBarChangeListener) this); 
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rodykle);
            // Getting width & height of the given image.
            int w = bmp.getWidth();
            int h = bmp.getHeight();
            // Setting post rotate to 90
            Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
            mtx.postRotate(progress);
            // Rotating Bitmap
            Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
            BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(rotatedBMP);
            img.setImageDrawable(bmd);  

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: 1)clean your project..2)uninstall from device..3)Re-Run the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener((OnSeekBarChangeListener) this);` line

Look closely in your class code

Below line:

```
 seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener((OnSeekBarChangeListener) this);
```

Tries to type case Activity into `OnSeekBarChangeListener` and on next line you are attaching a new  `OnSeekBarChangeListener`. So just remove this line.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your generated files are corrupted/not updated.
Try going to Project-> Clean.